# Getting Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' --> ' to data type int. How do I solve this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I made a trigger for when a table is updated. This is a bit of its code:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john',
             CAST(D.eventStart AS nvarchar(30)) + ' --> ' + CAST(I.eventStart AS nvarchar(30)),
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id
```

I'm using the CAST because eventStart is of the type dateTime2 and I want it to be nvarchar in this case.

What I'm trying to do is take the 2 dates and the ' --> ' and insert them into a String (changes)

The problem is when I run the application I get:

"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' --> ' to data type int."

I'm almost sure the problem has something to do with the CAST line. Any idea why and how to fix this?

PS: changes is of the type nvarchar(MAX).

UPDATE:

All Trigger code:

```
USE [ITApiContext-20150205100935]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[EventUpdate]    Script Date: 10-Mar-15 11:55:16 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[EventUpdate]
   ON  [dbo].[Events]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON;

       INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.name + ' --> ' + I.name, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.project + ' --> ' + I.project, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.project + ' --> ' + I.project, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.objectives + ' --> ' + I.objectives, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.city + ' --> ' + I.city, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.country + ' --> ' + I.country, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             (CAST(D.eventStart AS nvarchar(30)) + N' --> ' + CAST(I.eventStart AS nvarchar(30))), 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id



        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             CAST(D.departure AS nvarchar(30)) + N' --> ' + CAST(I.departure AS nvarchar(30)), 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             CAST(D.arrival AS nvarchar(30)) + N' --> ' + CAST(I.arrival AS nvarchar(30)), 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.registration + ' --> ' + I.registration, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.nationalTransportation + ' --> ' + I.nationalTransportation, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.accommodation + ' --> ' + I.accommodation, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.acNumberNights + ' --> ' + I.acNumberNights, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.acPreferHotel + ' --> ' + I.acPreferHotel, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.acPreferHotelUrl + ' --> ' + I.acPreferHotelUrl, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.flight + ' --> ' + I.flight, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             CAST(D.flDeparture AS nvarchar(30)) + N' --> ' + CAST(I.flDeparture AS nvarchar(30)), 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.flDepartPrefer + ' --> ' + I.flDepartPrefer, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.flDepartPreferUrl + ' --> ' + I.flDepartPreferUrl, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             CAST(D.flReturn AS nvarchar(30)) + N' --> ' + CAST(I.flReturn AS nvarchar(30)), 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.flRetPrefer + ' --> ' + I.flDepartPrefer, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.flDepartPreferUrl + ' --> ' + I.flDepartPreferUrl, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.notes+ ' --> ' + I.notes, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id
END
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the code that is causing the failure?  Your types seem to be aligned, according to the information in your question.

Comment: I could post the entire trigger if you want but yes I think it has something to do with this code. specifically the CAST line

Comment: I don't see any problem in that part you have posted, seems to be problem somewhere else.

Comment: change it to: `CAST(D.eventStart AS nvarchar(30)) + CAST(I.eventStart AS nvarchar(30))` and see what happens.  You'll probably still get an error, but possibly closer to the actual problem.

Comment: I've posted all the trigger. PS: I'm bad/new at TSQL so the possibility of a newbie mistake is high

Comment: What is the type of the `changes` column?

Comment: As said in the question changes is of the type nvarchar(MAX)

Comment: Check my answer, use `Try-Catch` to detect in which line is problem.

Comment: @VítorMartins: Have you checked one `INSERT` at a time in the trigger (i.e. comment out all other statements, so you know for sure which `INSERT` statement is throwing that error)? Once you minimise the issue to one statement, you can check the column data types etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(CAST(D.eventStart AS nvarchar(30)) + N' --> ' + CAST(I.eventStart AS nvarchar(30)))
```

As per the comments, the thing that finally did the trick:

```
CAST(CAST(D.eventStart AS nvarchar(30)) + '-->' + CAST(I.eventStart AS nvarchar(30)) AS nvarchar(max))
```

double-casting for the win.

Comment: Tried it, still got:

"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' --> ' to data type int."

Comment: @VítorMartins check If `Changes` is really of `NVARCHAR` type

Comment: Well this is all trial and error since we can't see your types or trigger, but to make absolutely sure that the string is interpreted as nvarchar why don't you try casting the entire "column", for example: CAST(CAST(date as nvarchar) + '-->' + CAST(otherdate as nvarchar) AS nvarchar(max)). If this still fails, the problem is most definately on the other end.

Comment: This worked! thanks everyone! sorry for all the trouble

Comment: Update your answer as is in your comment and I'll accept it ;)

Comment: Glad it helped, although a bit surprised myself ;-) Answer updated

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Try-Catch` to detect where is the problem. After tru problem will be detected will be possible to find solution.

Also this line: `D.acNumberNights + ' --> ' + I.acNumberNights,` Are you sure that `acNumberNights` is type of `NVARCHAR`? Shouldn't cast you this?

```
USE [ITApiContext-20150205100935]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[EventUpdate]    Script Date: 10-Mar-15 11:55:16 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[EventUpdate]
   ON  [dbo].[Events]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRY
       SET NOCOUNT ON;

       INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.name + ' --> ' + I.name, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.project + ' --> ' + I.project, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.project + ' --> ' + I.project, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.objectives + ' --> ' + I.objectives, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.city + ' --> ' + I.city, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.country + ' --> ' + I.country, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             (CAST(D.eventStart AS nvarchar(30)) + N' --> ' + CAST(I.eventStart AS nvarchar(30))), 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id



        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             CAST(D.departure AS nvarchar(30)) + N' --> ' + CAST(I.departure AS nvarchar(30)), 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             CAST(D.arrival AS nvarchar(30)) + N' --> ' + CAST(I.arrival AS nvarchar(30)), 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.registration + ' --> ' + I.registration, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.nationalTransportation + ' --> ' + I.nationalTransportation, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.accommodation + ' --> ' + I.accommodation, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.acNumberNights + ' --> ' + I.acNumberNights, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.acPreferHotel + ' --> ' + I.acPreferHotel, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.acPreferHotelUrl + ' --> ' + I.acPreferHotelUrl, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.flight + ' --> ' + I.flight, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             CAST(D.flDeparture AS nvarchar(30)) + N' --> ' + CAST(I.flDeparture AS nvarchar(30)), 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.flDepartPrefer + ' --> ' + I.flDepartPrefer, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.flDepartPreferUrl + ' --> ' + I.flDepartPreferUrl, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             CAST(D.flReturn AS nvarchar(30)) + N' --> ' + CAST(I.flReturn AS nvarchar(30)), 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.flRetPrefer + ' --> ' + I.flDepartPrefer, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.flDepartPreferUrl + ' --> ' + I.flDepartPreferUrl, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id

        INSERT INTO [dbo].Logs([date],[name],[changes],[eventId])
             SELECT getdate(), 'john', 
             D.notes+ ' --> ' + I.notes, 
             I.id
             FROM Inserted I
                  INNER JOIN Deleted D ON I.id = D.id
     END TRY
     BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE(),
               ERROR_LINE()
     END CATCH
END
```